# No networks defined on Openstack Base

Tags: openstack

My Lab:

- 1 VM for MAAS 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM vnet 10.20.81.0/24
- 1 VM for JUJU 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM vnet 10.20.81.0/24
- 1 VM for LANDSCAPE 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM vnet 10.20.81.0/24
- 4 VM for OPENSTACK 400GBx2 HDD + 16GB RAM 2 vnet 10.20.81.0/24 & 10.20.82.0/24

The deploy of Openstack Base on my lab went well no issue, but if I try to create a new instance with a new user obtain this result:
("No networks defined") I don't know why.

Of following the screen:

[image]

**Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "u1604svr", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance cbd238d1-cb41-45ca-8f99-00a3f168003f. Last exception: No networks defined. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/conductor/mana].**

Its own networks on Openstack has been created in this way

[image]

both networks are added on all vnodes on Maas, as shown here

[image]

the nova-conductor.log is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25061287/). Anyone can help me to resolve that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn how configure the network in Openstack I've made a second lab where I've deployed Openstack Autopilot and replied the same network configuration on my first lab. Now that works fine.

My error was consider the network 10.20.82.0/24 as internal net otherwise the right setting is the following:

on admin user:
[image]

on generic user
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your nova-conductor logs, there is no defined network for the corresponding user. You can find more information in neutron logs. This may occur due to IAM(roles and access rights).

One suggestion is create new private(internal) network by the user(rm@mail.com) then try to create VM on the newly created private network.

Comment: I've done your suggest leaving create the private network by user, but nothing the same error, consider that user has the admin privileges.